# $\neg \text{CH}$ within an inner model

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

I know that $\text{ZFC}$ cannot prove the consistency of $\text{ZFC} + \neg \text{CH}$ through inner models, since $\text{V} = \text{L}$ is consistent with $\text{ZFC}$ and within the constructible universe $\text{GCH}$ holds. But I was wondering whether we could prove it through inner models (of $\text{ZFC}$) by assuming the existence of some large cardinals, like for example measurable cardinals, or by simply assuming directly $\text{V} \neq \text{L}$. I know, of course, that this would be a **very** suboptimal relative consistency result, but I still wonder if such an inner model could exists and what should it look like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $0^\#$ exists, then there is some ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha$ is countable in $V$, but $\alpha$ is inaccessible in $L$. In particular, $\omega_3^L$ is countable.

This means that $\operatorname{Add}(\omega,\omega_2)^L$ has only countably many dense subsets in $V$. So there is some generic filter meeting them. Therefore there is an inner model of $L[0^\#]$ in which $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$. This can be extended, wildly, as shown by Solovay. There is an inner model of $L[0^\#]$ in which $\sf GCH$ fails on a proper class.

Of course, since a lot of "very complicated" forcings in $L$ are still all countable in $V$, we can replace Cohen reals by essentially any forcing in $L$ which would force that the continuum is below $\alpha$. So in fact any "reasonable" forcing proof over $L$ becomes reality in the presence of $0^\#$ (e.g. Martin's Axiom, etc.)

The same holds if we have a measurable cardinal, etc. since it implies the existence of $0^\#$.

---

Let me point out that the large cardinal axioms below $0^\#$ are *in general* consistent with $V=L$, so they are not useful here.

Comment: Very belatedly (I +1ed long ago fwiw), a quick comment: it's separately worth noting that such an inner model of $L[0^\sharp]$ can be found canonically: If $W\models$ "$0^\sharp$ exists," we can use the $L[0^\sharp]^W$-ordering to pick out an explicit $X$ such that $L[X]\models 2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$. So even though forcing is involved in the description, we really do have a canonical model construction in the sense of a specific formula $\varphi$ such that whenever $W\models$ "$0^\sharp$ exists" we have that $\varphi^W$ is an inner model of $W$ satisfying $\mathsf{ZFC+2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2}$.

Comment: This raises a follow-up meta-question: is there a more satisfying way to phrase the question "is there a canonical way to build an inner model in which $\mathsf{CH}$ fails?" so that this sort of thing is ruled out (since it does feel "morally" like forcing)?

Comment: (Sorry, two comments prior "inner model of $L[0^\sharp]$" should be "inner model of $\neg\mathsf{CH}$," and "$L[X]$" should be "$L[X]^W$." Coffee hadn't kicked in yet.)

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of $(*)$? Providing canonicity to $\lnot\sf CH$?

Comment: Maybe. What is $(*)$?

Comment: That complicated axiom about $\Bbb P_{\max}$ and genericity.

Comment: Does that actually produce a canonical model? I thought it produced a canonical *theory*, but the model itself depends on the generic $g$.

Comment: No, that's the point. There is a canonical candidate for a generic, and $(*)$ says that it is indeed generic. At least that's what I understood from my conversations with David Asperó about it over the years.

Comment: Oh fascinating, I wasn't aware of that. Do you have a citation I can follow?

Comment: Not really, but I'd guess any of Woodin's paper about CH pre-Ultimate L, or maybe the introduction of the paper in Annals about it and MM.